# Are there any academic studies of productivity gains of Resharper?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, resharper

I have a new job, and one of my first tasks is to convince my boss that Resharper is a wonderful idea - which it is. Are any of you aware of any academic studies of Resharpers productivity gains? My boss likes numbers, but the only numbers I can find are rather unsupported statements by Jetbrains.

So, for now my best arguments are "I really, really like it Boss" and "Pleaaase!!!"

Comment: At this point, I'm not aware of any. We're thinking of executing a controlled experiment here at JetBrains but no specific time estimates so far. Can you advise what kind of answers/numbers your boss would be interested in getting?

Comment: @gorohoroh, the main number would be time saved -- if possible specified feature by features. Other interesting numbers could be:  Comparative number of build breaks, failed unit tests, Execution errors Errors, crashes etc.

Comment: @Morten I am not sure you know Resharper that well if you can't justify why it is so good :). Just show your boss this video: http://tv.jetbrains.net/videocontent/why-resharper-is-awesome (or any other on the Jetbrains site). If it's down to license cost then download the free 30 day trial and prove for yourself that it can impove your workflow and helps create more solid, clean code. The reduction of code debt alone would more than make up for the license cost.

Comment: @Piers Myers, Yes I know it well and absolutely love it. I know how much it improves my work. I can probably convince my boss, but the thing is: He has to convince his boss, and the procurement department. If the standard setup for developer machines is to be broken, the organisation needs more than the workd of a newly hired grunt. Apart from my situation, I think it would be interesting to see studies of tools like Resharper.

Comment: I think the question would be: how does your organization measure the value of tools? How does it measure productivity? Is it feature points/sprint, LOC/day, ...? Once you know what to measure, simply measure a period without and a period with R# (Trial) and compare...

Comment: @RoyDictus, Yes a controlled experiment of my own might be the solution for me. I was just wondering, if anyone had already done that in a larger more academic, and perhaps published scale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, I convinced my boss without using academic studies as an argument. We bought it, I made a small demonstration of what the (very small) investment, and he was very pleased. What he liked the most was:

1. The live and file templates (obvious and very meassurable time saving)
2. Refactoring (maintain quality).
3. Effective Short cuts (time saving).
4. Test test runner (time saving, maintain and increase quality)

So, it turns out, I did not need studies of Resharper effectiveness, but I am still interested.